# Open JPEG/Image file from GridView in new Tab in browser ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a GridView which Lists Filename, type of Document and Unique Asset Number. You Select Asset and then Document Type which Filters the GridView List to just include those records relating to that particular Asset and e.g. Photographs. On Selecting Open File this will open PDF Files in a Browser window (Code courtesy of StackOverflow). This works fine with PDF's but when I try to open say a JPEG File with modified Code it just Downloads the File.

I have tried every solution that I can search for but the only alternative that works so far utilises a Panel in asp.net, which is not what the users want.

```
    protected void grdAttachment_RowCommand(object sender, 
   GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "ViewFile")
        {
            string fileName = Server.MapPath("~/Attachment/" + 
   e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            string extension = fileName.Substring(fileName.Length - 3);
            if (extension != "pdf")
            {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
                string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
                string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base64);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", 
  "application/Photos");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content- 
  Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }

            else // WORKS!!
            {
                //string path = 
   Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Attachment/"), fileName);
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(fileName);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", 
   "application/pdf");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content- 
   Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
```

Image Files are just Downloaded

Comment: You have no control over that. It is the settings of the browser of the user that determines if the file gets downloaded or displayed in a window.

Comment: Thanks but why then does it work for PDF Files?

Comment: This works but I cannot ask all the users to go into their browsers and alter settings.